# split columns wrt column names using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
(A,B)   (B,C)   (D,B)   (E,F)
  0      3        0       1
  1      1        3       0
  2      2        4       2
```

I want to split it into different columns for all columns in `df` as shown below:

```
A   B   B   C   D   B   E   F
0   0   3   3   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   3   3   0   0
2   2   2   2   4   4   2   2
```

and add similar columns together:

```
 A  B   C   D   E   F
 0  3   3   0   1   1
 1  5   1   3   0   0
 2  6   2   4   2   2
```

how to achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use this :

```
out = (
        df
          .T
          .reset_index()
          .assign(col= lambda x: x.pop("index").str.strip("()").str.split(","))
          .explode("col")
          .groupby("col", as_index=False).sum()
          .set_index("col")
          .T
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
​
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  3  3  0  1  1
1  1  5  1  3  0  0
2  2  8  2  4  2  2
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... im getting this error "KeyError: 'index'"

Comment: Seems like you have tuples as column names/indexes. Can you `print(df.columns)` and/or `print(df.sample(3).to_dict("list"))?`

Comment: how can i remove this indexing 0,1,2 in output

Comment: If you mean the display, use this : `print(out.to_string(index=False))` or if you're saving it to a csv use this : `out.to_csv("output_file.csv", index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to extract the variables in the header, then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), finally[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df
   .reset_index().melt('index')
   .assign(variable=lambda d: d['variable'].str.findall('(\w+)'))
   .explode('variable')
   .pivot_table(index='index', columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  3  3  0  1  1
1  1  5  1  3  0  0
2  2  8  2  4  2  2
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'(A,B)': [0, 1, 2],
                   '(B,C)': [3, 1, 2],
                   '(D,B)': [0, 3, 4],
                   '(E,F)': [1, 0, 2]})
```

##### printing/saving without index:

```
print(out.to_string(index=False))
 A  B  C  D  E  F
 0  3  3  0  1  1
 1  5  1  3  0  0
 2  8  2  4  2  2


# as file
out.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... im getting this error "KeyError: 'index'

Comment: @karthik does your index have an initial name? In this case use it instead of "index". please provide a reproducible input that triggers this error

Comment: how can i remove this indexing 0,1,2 in output

Comment: @karthik this is the index, you cannot remove it, except if you want to print: `print(out.to_string(index=False))`, or save: `out.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

i think (A, B) as tuple

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df[i].tolist()] * len(i), index=list(i)) for i in df.columns]).sum(level=0).T
```

result:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   3   3   0   1   1
1   1   5   1   3   0   0
2   2   8   2   4   2   2
```

if future warning occur, use following code:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df[i].tolist()] * len(i), index=list(i)) for i in df.columns]).groupby(level=0).sum().T
```

same result

Comment: can i remove this indexing 0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with removed levels with `MultiIndex` in columns by [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.findall('(\w+)').map(tuple)

df = (pd.concat([df.droplevel(x, axis=1) for x in range(df.columns.nlevels)], axis=1)
        .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
        .sum())
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  3  3  0  1  1
1  1  5  1  3  0  0
2  2  8  2  4  2  2
```

For write ouput to file without index use:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```